# TinyMCE pegar e setar valor

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Como eu pego e seto o valor do [plugin TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/)?

tinymce é um plugin textarea com varias opções é uma caixa de formatação de texto, quando eu digo pegar o valor eu quero dizer o que foi formatado pelo usuário por exemplo um texto em negrito com tamanho 16 e etc

Comment: Poderia descrever melhor o problema/resposta para que outras pessoas possam identificar esse conteúdo com facilidade

Comment: Eu sei que você já aceitou uma resposta, mas apenas para que isso seja potencialmente útil para outras pessoas no futuro: o que é o "valor do plugin"? Pela resposta parece que você quer dizer o conteúdo textual sendo editado pelo plugin, certo?

Comment: @LuizVieira  esse plugin é uma textarea com varias opções é uma caixa de formatação de texto, quando eu digo pegar o valor eu quero dizer o que foi formatado pelo usuário por exemplo um texto em negrito com tamanho 16 e etc

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha Pois é, veja como com esse texto do seu comentário o "problema" fica bem mais claro. Eu sugiro que você edite sua questão e adicione esse tipo de informação lá. Assim a pergunta fica mais clara, facilita para que mais pessoas possam postar respostas interessantes e até te ajuda a ganhar reputação porque atrai interesse para a pergunta. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tinyMCE.get('mensagem').getContent();  /* Pegar valor tinyMCE */

tinymce.get('mensagem').setContent('');  /* Popular campos e limpar campos */
```

Comment: Caro amigo, por favor, adicione uma explicação melhor à sua resposta apenas código é muito simplório, poderia especificar?

Answer (score 2):

```
tinyMCE.get('seuid').getContent();  /* get */

tinymce.get('seuid').setContent('');  /* set */
```

Comment: Olá. Sei que a resposta já foi aceita, mas você talvez pudesse melhorá-la um pouquinho indicando, por exemplo, o que o usuário deve passar como "seuid". Sei que a resposta já ajudou o Silvio (e isso é muito bom!), mas se for melhorada um pouquinho ela pode ajudar outras pessoas no futuro que não conhecem muito do assunto. :)

Answer (score 0):

Para setar:

```
window.parent.tinymce.get('id_do_seu_textarea').getBody().innerHTML = '<%= row.data %>';
```